# How to call constructor of class in generic method?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create generic function to minimize repeated code.
I have following function (without Generic applied)

```
public ModelClass getModelDataList (String arg1)
{
        ModelClass objModelClass = new ModelClass(new JSONObject(arg1));
        return objModelClass;
}
```

so now i am trying to make it generic so that i can Use any ModelClass with it (e.g. Student,Department, College etc)
so i found code by searching on Google

```
public static <T> T f(String response) 
    {
        T typeList = new T(new JSONObject(response));
        return typeList ;
    }
```

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the error comes at new T(new JSONObject(response)) telling me that no T defined(Cannot instantiate the type T)

Comment: This will be a dupe of many...

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't constrain a generic parameter to have a particular constructor. Nor should you want to.

The standard course of action is to pass in the abstract factory. Java SE 8 may well introduce a concise form for single method interfaces.

Comment: Can you provide me some code to do this action in different way as you say with abstract factory?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another way to do this by making use of interfaces & abstract method inheritance